# jQuery hover - div does not show up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code:

```
$("#people td, #list td").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: "#444"
    }, "fast");
    $(this).find(".controls").stop().fadeIn("fast");
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: "#333"
    }, "fast");
    $(this).find(".controls").stop().fadeOut("fast");
});

$("#list .controls").hide();
```

`.controls` is a div, which contains some links to work with entry (there are for example 10 entries on the page). Everything worked until this moment and now it's not working anymore.
When I open the page, `.controls` hide - that's ok.
But when I hover over the `td`, css animation runs, but fadeIn does not. Same goes with the fadeOut in the second function (when mouseleave event is triggered).

HTML is as following:

```
<td>
    <div class="icons">

</div>
<div class="profile">
    <div class="info">
    <div class="name">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
    <a href="http://...">Link</a>
            <a href="http://...">Link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: I'd need to see your HTML but I bet controls is not a child of each of your td elements. Maybe?

Comment: It might help if you posted a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

That's weird. I removed the .stop() after both .find(".controls") and now it's working.
Little problem is, when you hover in and out couple times the animation then runs a few more times.

Comment: And now I put the .stop() back where it originally was and it runs too.. o.O